Expo React Native/IOS: App fails to build on device when apple sign in included
The build fails with following error:
 error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: xxxxxx" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.applesignin entitlement

I do not have a paid apple developer account. Do I need a paid developer account for this?

To use the Apple Sign In feature in your app, you must include the required permissions in your provisioning profile. Unfortunately, the free Apple Developer account does not support certain features, such as Apple Sign In. As a result, you will need a paid Apple Developer account to solve this issue and properly develop your app with the necessary rights.
To fix the build error and use Apple Sign In, you'll need to get a Apple Developer account. This will let you build a provisioning profile with the necessary permissions for your app.
